# Отсортировать в ларавел чеерез промежуточную таблицу много ко многим

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, many-to-many

Помогите сделать сортировку.
Есть таблицы

```
  create table devices
(
    id              bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    number          varchar(64)             null,
    code            int unsigned            null,
    counter         varchar(255) default '' not null,
    date_check      datetime                null,
    last_answer     datetime                null,
    device_type_id  bigint unsigned         not null,
    status          tinyint                 not null,
    device_place_id bigint unsigned         not null,
    location_id     bigint unsigned         not null,
    created_at      timestamp               null,
    updated_at      timestamp               null,
    raw_data        text                    not null,
    personal_number varchar(255) default '' not null)

create table parameters
(
    id             bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name           varchar(255) default '' not null,
    device_type_id int                     not null,
    title          varchar(255) default '' not null
)
create table device_parameter
(
    device_id    bigint unsigned not null,
    parameter_id bigint unsigned not null,
    value        float           null,
    date         datetime        null,
    id           bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    created_at   timestamp       null,
    updated_at   timestamp       null,
    constraint device_parameter_device_id_foreign
        foreign key (device_id) references devices (id),
    constraint device_parameter_parameter_id_foreign
        foreign key (parameter_id) references parameters (id)
)
```

И модели
В Device.php

```
public function parameters() {
        /***
         *  device(id) -> device_data(device_id)
         */
        return $this->belongsToMany(Parameter::class)->withPivot('value', 'date')->orderBy('date', 'desc');
    }
    public function value() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DeviceParameter::class,'device_parameter');
    }
```

В parameter.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Parameter extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

В таблицу device_parameters заносяться показания приборов по датам и код параметра.
Мне нужно отсортировать таблицу devices по последним значениям из столбца device_parameter.value от большего к меньшему и наоборот. Так же возможна фильтрация по дате показаний.
Использую

```
 $this->query->join('device_parameter', 'devices.id', '=', 'device_parameter.device_id')
                    ->where('device_parameter.parameter_id',1)
                    ->orderBy('device_parameter.value','ASC');
```

Но получаю дублирующие записи. Как сделать правильно ?

Answer (score 0):

Ну если ты задал колонки `withPivot('value', 'date')`.

То можно сформировать запрос так.

```
Devices::with(['parameters' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderBy('pivot_value', 'asc');
}])->get();
```

Это будет работать, потому что `Eloquent` использует псевдоним для всех полей, представленных в `withPivot`, как `pivot_field_name`.

Ну или универсальным способом.

```
Devices::with(['parameters' => function ($q) {
    $q->orderBy('device_parameter.value', 'asc');
}])->get();
```